# Segmentation Fault after reading a file into a struct array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads data from a file and puts it into a struct array. I have succeeded in putting it into the array but I then get a segmentation fault. I believe I have to use malloc to initialize the struct array but I am new to programming and don't really understand how to do this. Thanks for your help! I have copied pieces of my code so you can see what I've done. I have not included my functions in this code.

```
struct Weather
{
    char location;
    int daynum;
    double temp;
    double precip;
};

int main (void)
{
    FILE*openFile;
    char buffer[COLS][ROWS];
    int i = 0;
    struct Weather loc1; //initialize here?

    for (i = 0; i <200; i++)
    {
        fgets (buffer[i], ROWS, openFile);
        parseLine(buffer[i], &loc1);
        printf ("%d %c %d %.2lf %.2lf\n",i, loc1.location, loc1.daynum, loc1.temp, loc1.precip);

    }
}
```

Comment: first problem: you need to open the file. Take a look at [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Comment: @Mason: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Your file stream (openFile) is not initialized; it does not actually point to a file. As [yano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476780/yano) said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878147/segmentation-fault-after-reading-a-file-into-a-struct-array#comment68971556_40878147), use [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) in order to properly initialize the file pointer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must initialize the file stream with [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) before any I/O operations!

   ```
   int main()
   {
       char filename[64];
       FILE *fp;

       snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "hello1234.txt");
       if(NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r")))
       {
           printf("err, failed when fopen(), %s %s[%d].\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
           return -1;
       }
       //your code here

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Initialize the struct

   Note that `malloc()` cannot initialize the struct.

   two methods：

   M0:

   struct Weather loc1; 
   memset(&loc1, 0, sizeof(struct Weather));

   M1:

   struct Weather loc1 = {0};
3. `man malloc` or click the link for a [malloc manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems in your code:

- The stream pointer `openFile` is uninitialized, calling `fgets()` for it invokes undefined behavior. You want to open a file for `fopen()` or set the value of `openFile` to the standard input stream `stdin`.
- The 2D `char` array should be defined in the other order:

  ```
  char buffer[ROWS][COLS];
  ```
- you should use the same constant for the loop counter and the 2D array definition: `ROWS` might be defined to something less than `200`.
- the size of the line buffer is `COLS`, pass that to `fgets()`.
- you should test the return value of `fgets()`: it returns `NULL` at end of file and the contents of the destination array is indeterminate in this case.
- whether or not to initialize `loc1` depends on what the `parseLine()` function does. It would make sense that `parseLine()` make no assumptions about the contents of the destination structure, but the source has not been posted, so we cannot know for sure.
- the `printf` format specifier for type `double` is `%f`, the extra `l` is simply ignored.